# How to use "template" and "rowTemplate" field in syncfusion React DataGrid?

Tags: syncfusion

I am setting up a Data Grid table from React syncfusion in my application.

My application is built with antDesign Pro template, DvaJS, UmiJS, and ReactJS.
I have made the basic syncfusion Data Grid that uses default fields to fetch the cell data and it works fine.

As soon as I add "template" field to ColumnDirective or "rowTemplate" to GridComponent, I get the error.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import router from 'umi/router';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { Input } from 'antd';
import moment from 'react-moment';
import { ColumnDirective, ColumnsDirective, Filter, Grid, GridComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids';

@connect(({loading, data})=> ({
  data: data.data,
  loading: loading.effects['data/fetchData']
}))
class dataComponent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
    this.columnTemplate = this.columnTemplate;
  }    

  columnTemplate(props) {  
   return (
       <div className="image"><p>text</p></div>
    );
  }

render() {
    const { match, children, location, dispatch, data} = this.props;
    return (               
       <GridComponent dataSource={data}>
            <ColumnsDirective>
                 <ColumnDirective headerText='Heading' template={this.columnTemplate}/>
                 <ColumnDirective field='EmployeeID' headerText='Employee ID'/>
                 <ColumnDirective field='FirstName' headerText='Name'/>                       
             </ColumnsDirective>
       </GridComponent>
   );
}
```

---

Expected output:

Heading Employee ID FirstName

Text 123 John

---

In actual, it doesn't render anything after adding template field to code.

In console, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: str.match is not a function

```
at evalExp (template.js:65)
at compile (template.js:52)
at Object.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-grids/node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/template-engine.js.Engine.compile (template-engine.js:57)
at compile (template-engine.js:16)
at templateCompiler (util.js:145)
at new Column (column.js:131)
at prepareColumns (util.js:185)
at GridComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-grids/src/grid/base/grid.js.Grid.render (grid.js:704)
at GridComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids/src/grid/grid.component.js.GridComponent.render (grid.component.js:35)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14741)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14696)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15644)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19312)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19352)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18578)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19468)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20342)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20254)
at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20228)
at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:20097)
at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19911)
at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11169)
at DynamicComponent../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:335)
at dynamic.js:91
```

When I click on **template.js:65**
it show the following as error:

> var isClass = str.match(/class="([^\"]+|)\s{2}/g);

Here's the link to code I am trying to follow:
[Syncfusion template example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/grid/column-template)

I'd highly appreciate your help!

Comment: can you post you full code

Comment: Sure, I have posted the full code now.

Answer (score 0):

Query #1: How to use the column template on Syncfusion EJ2 Grid in React platform.

You can customize the own element instead of field value in EJ2 Grid column. Please refer the below code example, sample and Help Documentation for more information.

```
export class ColumnTemplate extends SampleBase { 
constructor() { 
    super(...arguments); 
    this.template = this.gridTemplate; 
} 
gridTemplate(props) { 

     return ( 
   <div className="image"><p>text</p></div>  //Here defined your element 
); 
} 
render() { 
    return (<div className='control-pane'> 
            <div className='control-section'> 
                <GridComponent dataSource={employeeData} width='auto' height='359'> 
                    <ColumnsDirective> 
                        <ColumnDirective headerText='Heading' width='180' template={this.template} textAlign='Center'/> 
                        <ColumnDirective field='EmployeeID' headerText='Employee ID' width='125' textAlign='Right'/> 
                        <ColumnDirective field='FirstName' headerText='Name' width='120'/>                            
                    </ColumnsDirective> 
                </GridComponent> 
            </div> 
        </div>); 
}
```

}

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gdraob?file=index.js

Help Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/grid/columns/#column-template

Query #2: How to use the row template on Syncfusion EJ2 Grid in React platform.

We have provided the EJ2 Grid with row template feature support it is allow template for the row and we have rendered element instead of each Grid row. Please refer the below code example, sample and Help Documentation for more information.

```
export class RowTemplate extends SampleBase { 
constructor() { 
    super(...arguments); 
    this.format = (value) => { 
        return instance.formatDate(value, { skeleton: 'yMd', type: 'date' }); 
    }; 
    this.template = this.gridTemplate; 
} 
gridTemplate(props) { 

    return (<tr className="templateRow">             
        <td className="details"> 
            <table className="CardTable" cellPadding={3} cellSpacing={2}> 
                   .     .     .     . 
                </tbody> 
            </table> 
        </td> 
    </tr>); 
} 
render() { 
    return (<div className='control-pane'> 
            <div className='control-section'> 
                <GridComponent dataSource={employeeData} rowTemplate={this.template.bind(this)} width='auto' height='335'> 
                    <ColumnsDirective>                             
                        <ColumnDirective headerText='Employee Details' width='300' textAlign='Left' /> 
                    </ColumnsDirective> 
                </GridComponent> 
            </div> 
       </div>); 
}
```

}

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ka9ixk?file=index.js

Please get back to us, if you need further assistance.

Regards,

Thavasianand S.